# How to get an array of members of an array

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

Suppose I have a class

```
public class Foo
{
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have another class

```
public class Gloop
{
    public List<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}
```

What's the easiest way to get a `List<Bar>` of Foo.Bars?

I'm using C# 4.0 and can use Linq if that is the best choice.

UPDATE:

Just for a little dose of reality, the reason for this is that I have a Windows Service class that contains an inner ServiceBase derived class as a property.  So I end up with code like this:

```
public class Service
{
    public ServiceBase InnerService { get; set; }
}

public class ServiceHost
{
    private List<Service> services = new List<Service>();
    static void Main()
    {
         // code to add services to the list
         ServiceBase.Run(services.Select(service => service.InnerService).ToArray());
    }
}
```

Comment: what is Bar? is it a class or what is it?

Comment: Good catch, fixed.  A class obviously.

Comment: I didn't think it was obvious :) I was stumped actually ..lol. Anyways time to goto bed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one's simple, if I've understood you rightly:

```
List<Foo> foos = gloop.Foos; // Or wherever you're getting it from
List<Bar> bars = foos.Select(foo => foo.Bar)
                     .ToList();
```

If you only need an `IEnumerable<Bar>` you can just use `Select` without the call to `ToList`. Of course you don't need the `foos` local variable if you don't want it - you can just have a single statement. I've only separated them out in case you've got an existing `List<Foo>` or `Foo[]` (you mention arrays in your subject line).

Comment: What's more efficient, the Select with lambda, or something like (from b in gloop.Foos select b.Bar).ToList()

Comment: @Mystere Man: They end up as the same IL, but I don't see any reason for using a query expression when you're just doing a simple projection. It's extra clutter.

Comment: Since he mentioned Linq, the Linq equivalent for the second statement should be:
List<Bar> bars = (from f in foos.Bar select f).ToList();

Comment: Good point Jon, as usual, you're the voice of reason and wisdom ;)

Comment: @mynameiscoffey: Why? LINQ doesn't necessitate the use of query expressions IMO. We're still using LINQ to Objects, but taking the simplest syntax for the situation, IMO. Not to mention the fact that your query wouldn't work as written ;)

Comment: Ran it through LinqPad, both the lambda and linq compile to the exact same IL

Comment: @mynameiscoffee: Um, not the query expression your comment shows, which is trying to use `foos.Bar` as a source, and just selecting `f`. If you use the query expression that Mystere Man specified *then* it would give the same IL. But again, LINQ != query expressions. Both syntax forms are using LINQ.

Comment: I was talking in response to your comment to Mystere Man, you guys type faster than me ;).  I was genuinely curious (as it sounded like Mystere Man was as well).  Linq is new grounds to me, forgive my ignorance with naming and my bad query expression.

Comment: @mynameiscoffey: No problem :) Basically the compiler does a translation from the query expression form to code which doesn't use query expressions before it generates the IL. See section 7.16 of the C# 4 spec.

Comment: I wasn't aware that Linqpad showed you the IL generated.. i really need to start using that more...

Comment: Wow, just ran that through Linqpad and you're absolutely right, identical code for both.  You taught me two things today Jon.. a twofer

Answer (score 1):

`var bars = gloop.Foos.Select(foo => foo.Bar);`

Comment: As stated in another answer, this only returns `IEnumerable<Bar>`.  Use `ToList()` if you need it as `List<Bar>`.

Comment: did you forget to add the "ToList()"? or is that the return type of the Select call?

Comment: Yes, I forgot the `ToList()` in my initial (quick) answer.  IList adds some additional functionality to IEnumerable, like insert/delete which may be inappropriate given the source.